# Soft Question: What Does "Zero Density" mean in prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm reading through an article on Paul Erdos (http://www.ams.org/notices/199801/vertesi.pdf) and on page 22 they mention the following:

> Calling 714 and 715 a
>   “Ruth-Aaron pair”, we conjectured that such pairs
>   have density 0: that is, the set of n, such that the
>   sum of the prime factors of n is equal to the sum
>   of the prime factors of n+ 1, has density 0.

What does it mean for pairs to have a density of zero? I've searched around the webs and it seems to be in general usage without much being said about it otherwise? I get that they are defining it by saying "the set of n...."; but, I'm still not sure what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(x)$ be the number of integers $n$, $n\le x$, such that $n$ and $n+1$ form a Ruth-Aaron pair. What "density zero" means is that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{A(x)\over x}=0$$

Comment: It's also called "natural density", see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density).

Comment: Ah! That Wikipedia page helps a lot! Thanks Kahen.